# When reloading an Angular app go always to the root page ignoring routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a simple Angular app which uses the `router`.

My routing logic is simple

```
Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MyMainComponent },
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
]
```

If an error occurs in the app, the logic navigates to the ErrorComponent and therefore what I see on the browser url is `http://localhost:4200/error`.

If the user reloads the app from here (e.g. with `CMD+R`) the app goes back to the **Error** page. Is there a way to force a reload to go to the **Main** even if we reload a url pointing to an existing route path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the question of design.
You should give angular information if error really happened.

- It might be a service which stores last error and when navigation is performed this service is checked. So when page is refreshed, the service would not contain anything and you can navigate to default route
- or you can provide additional queryparameter to the `error` route which would be removed when navigation ends and when user refresh the page it would not be in the url. So the only way to see this param – navigate inside of the app.

In fact these approaches are alike – different just in the way you store information of internal navigation.

Not depenging on what approach you choose, for restricting navigation to specific route you can use CanActivate guard https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Answer (score 2):

Here will be my approach to this problem.

1.) Wrap your components inside a root component, like this

```js
Routes = [
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, children:[
  { path: '', component: MyMainComponent },
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent }
  ]
]
```

2.) In the constructor of your **HomeComponent** store the last navigated url in localstroage.

```js
  constructor(private router: Router) {

    this.router.events
    .pipe(filter((rs): rs is NavigationEnd => rs instanceof NavigationEnd))
    .subscribe(event => {
      localStorage.setItem("lastUrl",event.url);
    })

  }
```

3.) Listen to constructor of your AppModule (**this will be hit after every page refresh**), and check if last time the router was on certain page, then redirect to your desired page.

```js
  public constructor(private router: Router) {

    if(localStorage.getItem("lastUrl")=="/error")
    {
      localStorage.setItem("lastUrl",null);
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    
    }
  }
```